# Learning coding and "While True" usage is giving an error

Tags: python, while-loop

So, I am trying to learn Python and am using Python 3.6.0a3 on windows 10. As part of my practice I was trying to use the "while" loop and the editor says there is an error with my code and the cursor goes to 'While True"

My code is:

```
#Program to practice While and Continue
While True:
    Print('Who are you?')
    name=input()

    If name!='Joe':
    continue
    print('Hello Joe! What is the password? (It is a fish)')
    password-input()
    If password=='swordfish'
    break
print('Access granted')
```

I can't execute it!

Comment: Python is case sensitive.

Comment: `While`, `If`, and `Print` are not the same as `while`, `if`, and `print`

Comment: Incidentally, why are you on a Python 3.6 alpha build? That's not a stable release; Python 3.5.2 is the latest stable release.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example:

```
#Program to practice While and Continue
while True:
    print('Who are you?')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
      continue
    print('Hello Joe! What is the password? (It is a fish)')
    password = input()
    if password == 'swordfish':
      break
print('Access granted')
```

You had a bunch of syntax errors:

1. Python is case-sensitive, so `if`, `while` and `print` should all be in lower-case.
2. Conditional statements need to end with a colon `:`
3. Statements *inside* a conditional block need to be indented.

Further reading:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thank you!! Yes! You are right! I messed up with the uppercase "While." I also realized that indentation makes a huge difference in execution and isn't just about readability.